# Escaping html tags in html report

Tags: java, html

I have to write an HTML report from a java class which contains the source code of web pages. So the problem is that as soon as the source of a web page is encountered it is thought of by the browser as being the the end of html tags on the main report page and so the output is not renderd correctly. An example is shown below :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <li>
           <pre>
           <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
           <html>
           <head>
           <title>404 Not Found</title>
           </head><body>
           <h1>Not Found</h1>
           The page was not found on this server.
           </body>
           </html> 
           </pre>
        </li>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want that everything inside the pre tags must be taken as normal text and not html markup. I tried replacing `<` with `&lt;` , `>` with `&gt;` , `&` with `&amp;` etc.. but it doesnt seem to work. Any tips on how to make this possible?

EDIT : 
This is what i tried (a is the part inside pre tags)

```
File aFile = new File(filename);
try {
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(aFile,aFile.exists()));  
    a.replaceAll("<","&lt;");a.replaceAll(">","&gt;");a.replaceAll("\"","&;quot;");a.replaceAll("&","&amp;");
    out.write(a + "\r\n");    
    out.close();
}
```

EDIT 2:

So this correct solution involved a=a.replaceAll(...), but another thing to note is that if i replace < with &gt and later on i replace & with &amp (like i do in the above example), It will againn mess my output(< will become &lt;). So the order must also be changed(replcae & first and then <).

Comment: That will work.  You need to show us what you tried.

Comment: i used this a.replaceAll("<","&lt;");a.replaceAll(">","&gt;");a.replaceAll("\"","&;quot;");a.replaceAll("&","&amp;");           a is the part inside pre tags

Comment: Did you do `a = a.replaceAll("<", "&lt;"); a = ...`?

Comment: Java strings are immutable. That means `a.replaceAll` doesn’t change `a` but returns a new object.

Comment: the Nt found wa sbeing displayed as a heading. It should have been displayed as it is (i.e. <h1>Not Found</h1>)

Comment: @Gumbo, why are you posting that as a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: let me try a=a.replaceAll(...)

Comment: Consider using apache commons-lang StringEscapeUtils() to do that more efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do:

```
a = a.replaceAll("<","&lt;");
```

instead of :

```
a.replaceAll("<","&lt;");
```

and same for others...
As replaceAll method doesn't change the string, it rather returns a new one

Answer (score 2):

In Java, String objects are immutable. That means `a.replaceAll` doesn’t change `a` but returns a new String object in which the replacement took place.

So to fix this, you need to work with the returned object instead:

```
a = a.replaceAll("&","&amp;").replaceAll("<","&lt;");
```

And you actually only need to replace the `&` and `<` for your specific application.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence you post in the comment:

```
a.replaceAll("<","&lt;");
a.replaceAll(">","&gt;");
a.replaceAll("\"","&;quot;");
a‌​.replaceAll("&","&amp;");
```

won't work, since the [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method doesn't change the `String` it is called on. It can't, `String`s are *immutable* in Java.
Also, as @Rishabh points out, your last replace call will mess up the previous replaces, so you need to change the order.

You need to do

```
a = a.replaceAll("&","&amp;");
a = ...
```

Or, just do them all without saving the intermediate result:

```
a = a.replaceAll("&","&amp;").replaceAll("<","&lt;").replaceAll(">","&gt;").replaceAll("\"","&;quot;");
```

Also, you should probably use the [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method instead of `replaceAll()`, there is no need to use regexes in this case.

Comment: the order of the replace statements must be changed. Otherwise &lt; gets converted to &amp;lt; , and this will mess up the output

Answer (score 1):

Well.. `replaceAll` may work.. However, I'll always prefer to use [StingEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) as ..

```
a = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace this line:**

```
a.replaceAll("<","&lt;");a.replaceAll(">","&gt;");a.replaceAll("\"","&;quot;");a.replaceAll("&","&amp;");
```

**As this:**

```
a = a.replaceAll("<","&lt;").replaceAll(">","&gt;").replaceAll("\"","&;quot;").replaceAll("&","&amp;");
```